# How do I math on floats?

Tags: floating-point

I need an alternative to this simple math.

```
float FreqA = 28.333334;
FreqA = FreqA+0.000001;
println(FreqA);
```

However this results in 28.333336.  How do I perform this math to get the correct answer of 28.333335?

I have tried converting the float to an integer performing the math, than converting back to a float, but I get the same mathematical errors.

Comment: What environment are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are very high that your programming environment has a `double` datatype.
This type uses more memory than a `float`, but offers higher precision.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format